# Formula for monic quadratic polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

Let $p(x)$ be a monic quadratic polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$. Show that,for any integer $n$, there exists an integer $k$ such that
     $(p(n))(p(n+1))=p(k)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\;\;\;\;k = p(n)+n\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Hints are not necessairily answers, thank you very much.

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue In general, see [Do hints belong in answers or comments?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10589/do-hints-belong-in-answers-or-comments). If you have a question about this particular hint, then of course feel free to ask.

Comment: Oh, I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Let P(x)= x^2 + bx + c
Therefore, P(n)= n^2 + bn + c, for an arbitrary integer n

P(n+1) = (n+1)^2 + b(n+1) + c
=  n^2 + 2n + 1 + bn + b + c
= P(n) + 2n + b + 1

Therefore, P(n)P(n+1) = P(n)*{P(n) + 2n + b + 1}
= {P(n)}^2 + 2nP(n) + bP(n) + P(n)
= {P(n)}^2 + 2nP(n) + n^2 + bn + bP(n) +c
= (P(n) + n}^2 + b{P(n) + n} + c
= k^2 + bk + c , where k = P(n) + n,  (i.e) an integer,
= P(k)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).